# How to remove a bed slat holder (without breaking it)

Tags: bedroom

Is there a trick to remove those plastic slat holders without breaking them?

Ps: There is only a few milimeters gap (5 mm maybe), not enough for a small screw driver to play with the pin. (No way either to access the pin through the inside of the bed frame)[image]!
[image: the gap]!

Comment: So is the black rail square tubular steel?  Is there any way to look down the end of the tube?

Comment: How are the two sides of the frame attached to each other?  can you disassemble the frame to get the slats out?

Comment: @Paul thanks for your reply! Mission accomplished (answer bellow) No  way to access them from the tube as mentioned above. Dissembling the frame would not have changed anything since they are plugs into the frame. Unplug them with a screw driver did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These slats curve upwards just a little bit. Pull upward in the center of the slat, pushing one of the ends into its socket at the same time. The slat has enough flexibility to curve just a little more and clear the other socket.

Start in the center of the bed, this is where the frame has more flex and it is easier to work out how to do it.

HTH

Comment: It did work with a large flat screwdriver placed under the slat by levering on each side of the sockets (pulling one side and then the other). They somehow doesn't actually break as you said.

Comment: I found myself with the same problem some years back. ;-)

Comment: This worked for my wayfair bed, thanks!